# DataGrid's CellEditingTemplate and focus in edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I am having an issue with WPFToolkit `DataGrid` when a column is customized supplying both `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. If you take a look below, you will see my editing template has a single `CheckBox`. All is fine in a functional sense but when F2 is hit to edit the cell, one must also hit TAB in order for the `CheckBox` to receive focus. Ideally, one would hit F2 and SPACE to toggle the value. Currently, one must hit F2, TAB, SPACE. I have tried setting `TabIndex` to no avail. I am running out of ideas.

```
<WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Turn"
                                   MinWidth="60">
    <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="16">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanTurn}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/16/Tick.png" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=CanTurn}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</WPFToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Name="checkbox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CanTurn}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="checkbox" Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="checkbox" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=checkbox}" />
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Nice work.  Although it didn't work initially because I was working with SelectedItem property on the DataGrid.  Removed that and changed SelectionUnit="Cell" and this worked.

Answer (score 15):

Or this...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Long" IsReadOnly="False" Width="100">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=CanTurn}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: You could possibly also move it to a style..
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
          <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>

Comment: Nice work.  Although it didn't work initially because I was working with SelectedItem property on the DataGrid.  Removed that and changed SelectionUnit="Cell" and this worked.

Comment: What does this line actually do `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to set the focus on edit and select the text given by a Binding try this.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Parameter0, Mode=TwoWay}" Loaded="TbLoaded" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

code behind:

```
private void TbLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb == null) return;

    tb.SelectAll();
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, tb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!